# OpenGL texture loading issue in Android device

Tags: android, opengl-es

We are creating a cube on which we are loading textures. It is working fine in the emulator and in an HTC Desire device but in another device (LG Optimus,HTC Desire) the textures are not being loaded. Let us know if any one has solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet my hat that it's the texture dimensions. The emulator for some reason supports (and some of the examples use) odd dimensions like 192 x 192 which certain hardware will not support. Try a texture with dimensions that are a power of 2 like 128 x 128, or 256 x 256 etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the size of texture and also the resolution. Might be the underlying hardware doesn't support the dimensions for the texture you are using.